# SwiftUI Share Extension Not Showing in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'm trying to get my SwiftUI views to render when selecting the share extension I bundle with my app. This worked previously in iOS 15, but I'm wondering if anyone would be able to shed some light on how to fix it in iOS 16 (Granted, this might be a beta bug).

My share extension is outlined like this:

```swift
// ShareNavigationController.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Social

@objc(ShareNavigationController)
class ShareNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        initSwiftUI()
    }
    
    private func initSwiftUI() {
        // This is my SwiftUI View
        let rootView = AddURLView(viewModel: AddURLViewModel(extensionContext: self.extensionContext))
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
        view.addSubview(controller.view)
        
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        controller.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        controller.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

And the property list looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>ShareNavigationController</string>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>SUBQUERY(extensionItems, $extensionItem, SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, SUBQUERY($attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers, $uti, $uti UTI-CONFORMS-TO &quot;public.url&quot; AND NOT $uti UTI-CONFORMS-TO &quot;public.file-url&quot;).@count &gt;= 1).@count &gt;= 1).@count &gt;= 1
</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Devices running iOS 16 aren't able to show a view with this code. Is there something I've missed in how share extensions are handled in WWDC or is this something I should file a bug for?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was happening?